# Error of "variable might not initialized" while trying to use a class object as a parameter of a method, tried to use a IF to avoid the problem (JAVA)

Tags: java, oop

I'm learning JAVA and I was making the code for a product sales system in a store as an example. So I created the Product, Customer and Sale classes.

In my menu I check if there is a registered product or customer, if yes I call my sales method that has both parameters. However, NetBeans notifies an error that the variable has not been initialized even with the logic not to start the sale if the registration has not been done before.

My basic code:
"variable product might not have been initialized"
"variable customer might not have been initialized"

```
//Main
//Reg a client and a product, then perform a sale.
package store;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Store {
static boolean flagProduct=false, flagCustomer=false;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    menu();
   }
   
   public static void menu() {
   System.out.println("\n Choose option:\n"
   + "1 - Product Registration\n"
   + "2 - Customer Registration\n"
   + "3 - Sell\n"
   + "4 - End\n"
   );

   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   int select = scanner.nextInt();

   switch (select) {
       case 1:
       Product product = RegistProduct();
        System.out.print("\n Cod product : " + product.getCodProduct());
        System.out.print("\n Price product : " + product.getPriceProduct());
        System.out.print("\n Quantity product : " + product.getQuantProduct());
       menu();break;
       case 2:
       Customer customer = RegistCustomer();
       System.out.print("\n Cod Customer : " + customer.getCodCustomer());
       System.out.print("\n Customer name: " + customer.getName());
       menu();break;
       case 3:
           if(flagProduct == true && flagCustomer==true){ 
               Sale sale = sell(product, customer); // *****where the error happens*****
               System.out.print("\n Sale code : " + sale.getCodSale());
               System.out.print("\n Customer name: " + customer.getName());
               System.out.print("\n Cod product : " + product.getCodProduct()+ " -- Quantity:" + sale.getQuantSale()+ " -- Total:" + sale.getValueSale());
           } else if(flagProduct == true && flagCustomer==false){
               System.out.println("First register the customer ");
               menu();break;
           } else if(flagProduct == false && flagCustomer==true){
               System.out.println("First register the product");
               menu();break;
           } else
               System.out.println("First register the customer and product");
               menu();break;
       case 4:
       break;
       default:
       System.out.println("Error");
       menu();
   }
}

public static Product RegistProduct(){
   Product product = new Product();
   java.util.Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   
   System.out.print("Product code:\n");
   product.setCodProduct(scanner.nextInt());
   
   System.out.print("Product price:\n");
   product.setPriceProduct(scanner.nextFloat());
   
   System.out.print("Product quantity:\n");
   product.setQuantProduct(scanner.nextInt());
   flagProduct = true;
   return product;  
}

public static Customer RegistCustomer(){
   Customer customer = new Customer();
   java.util.Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   
   System.out.print("Customer name:\n");
   customer.setName(scanner.nextLine());
   
   System.out.print("Customer code:\n");
   customer.setCodCustomer(scanner.nextInt());
   
   flagCustomer=true;
   return customer;  
}


public static Sale Sell(Product product, Customer customer){
   java.util.Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   
   Random num = new Random();
   int codSale = num.nextInt(9999);
   
   Sale sale = new Sale();
    
   sale.setCodSale(codSale);
   
     
   System.out.print("Customer code:");
   int codSaleCustomer = scanner.nextInt();
   
   while (codSaleCustomer != customer.getCodCustomer()){
       System.out.print("Non-existent code. Please enter a valid code:\n");
       codSaleCustomer = scanner.nextInt();
   }
   
     
   System.out.print("Product code:");
   int codSaleProduct = scanner.nextInt();
   
   while (codSaleProduct != product.getCodProduct()){
       System.out.print("Non-existent code. Please enter a valid code:\n");
       codSaleProduct = scanner.nextInt();
   }
   
   System.out.print("Quantity of products purchased:\n");
   sale.setQuantSale(scanner.nextInt());
   
   sale.setValueSale(sale.getQuantSale()*product.getPriceProduct());
   
   product.setQuantProduct(product.getQuantProduct() - sale.getQuantSale());
   System.out.print("Remaining quantity in stock: "+ product.getQuantProduct());
   return sale;
}
}
```

```
//Class Product
package store;

public class Product {

private int codProduct;
private float priceProduct;
private int quantProduct;

    public int getCodProduct() {
        return codProduct;
    }

    public void setCodProduct(int codProduct) {
        this.codProduct = codProduct;
    }

    public float getPriceProduct() {
        return priceProduct;
    }

    public void setPriceProduct(float priceProduct) {
        this.priceProduct = priceProduct;
    }

    public int getQuantProduct() {
        return quantProduct;
    }

    public void setQuantProduct(int quantProduct) {
        this.quantProduct = quantProduct;
    }

}
```

```
//Class customer
package store;

public class Customer {
    private int codCustomer;
    private String name;

    public int getCodCustomer() {
        return codCustomer;
    }

    public void setCodCustomer(int codCustomer) {
        this.codCustomer = codCustomer;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

       
}
```

```
//Class sale
package store;

public class Sale extends Product{ //I dnno if extends is necessary
    private int codSale;
    private int quantSale;
    private float valueSale;

    public int getCodSale() {
        return codSale;
    }

    public void setCodSale(int codSale) {
        this.codSale = codSale;
    }

    public int getQuantSale() {
        return quantSale;
    }

    public void setQuantSale(int quantSale) {
        this.quantSale = quantSale;
    }

    public float getValueSale() {
        return valueSale;
    }

    public void setValueSale(float valueSale) {
        this.valueSale = valueSale;
    }
   
}
```

Comment: You should assign default values to all such variables first, to avoid this error.

Comment: The _reason_ you get the error at your indication: ... Notice how the `product` reference is defined within `case 1`, and the `customer` within `case 2`, but in `case 3` neither of those variables are known, which is why defaults are needed. So, it might be that the product and customer lines need to possibly be moved before to a point before the switch? Obviously, I'm not sure about the actual program flow/handling needs, but that would seem to help avoid the situation.